# How to run an SQL query via VBA

Tags: sql, vba

i am trying to run the following SQL query:

```
select a.isin
from Risk.BenchmarkFipFwdMainPort a
(where a.ValueDate =  (and a.Isin NOT IN (Select b.isin from Risk.BenchmarkFipCurrMainPort b where b.ValueDate = )))
```

via VBA with the above query stored in an Excel cell. The VBA code is:

Worksheets("Oversikt over papirer inn-ut").Range("A3:C10000").ClearContents

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
 cn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;" & _
     "Data Source=NBDBAG-DM1P,60000;" & _
     "Initial Catalog=PRADA;Integrated Security=SSPI"


Src = Worksheets("Oversikt over papirer inn-ut").Range("B1").Value & "'" & myDate & "'"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
     .Open Source:=Src, ActiveConnection:=cn
     
  '   Write the field names
    For Col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Oversikt over papirer inn-ut").Range("A3").Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, Col).Value = rs.Fields(Col).Name
    Next
     
  '   Write the recordset
    Worksheets("Oversikt over papirer inn-ut").Range("A3").Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

I get an error in VBA that says: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'. Does anyone have a  suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You don't put the date you want to have as parameter at the correct place(s), you just add it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SQL query correct?

> "where a.ValueDate =  (and a.Isin"

looks odd.

Do you mean this?

```
select 
   a.isin
from 
  Risk.BenchmarkFipFwdMainPort a
where 
  a.ValueDate = 'some date' and 
 a.Isin NOT IN 
(Select b.isin from Risk.BenchmarkFipCurrMainPort b where b.ValueDate = 'some date' );
```

Don't forget to quote the date.

Comment: *"Don't forget to quote the date"*: Even much better: Use ADODB.Parameter to pass the parameters. Makes it type safe and prevent SQL injection (okay, the latter is not that important if the SQL itself is in a sheet).

Comment: Thats true. But in this case it is better to try out if the SQL syntax is correct ;)